# Proof that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $P(x)=x^3-21x^2+5x+2$. I want to show that $P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Using the Mod $p$ Test, I can reduce $P(x)$ to $\bar P(x)=x^3+2x+2$ in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$, and show that $\bar P(x)$ has no zeroes in $\mathbb Z_3$ by trying $0,1,2$. So $\bar P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$, and deg$(\bar P(x))$=deg$(P(x))$, thus by the Mod $p$ Test, $P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Also you can apply rational root theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Well since this is a degree three polynomial all you have to show is that there is no root in $\mathbb{Q}$. By looking at the coefficients you can show that the only possible roots are $\pm 2, \pm1$. Since these are not roots, the polynomial is irreducible.

EDIT: If the polynomial $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^i $ has a rational root $\frac{p}{q}$ $(p,q)=1$, then $p|a_0$ and $q|a_n$.

Comment: What do you mean by "looking at the coefficients"?

Comment: Ill edit it into the answer.

Comment: I don't think we're allowed to use the rational root theorem, but thank you

Comment: @BCho: Unless I'm very much mistaken, the mod-p test is significantly more complicated than the rational root test!